# Can not change page

Tags: page-breaking

I am using Texmaker in windows 8 and I can not go beyond the second page in my document. This is a very similar problem to other questions answered here, yet I am asking because none of the solutions in the other questions were able to face the problem. Here is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{gobble}
\section{Question 1}
\subsection{Part a}


\begin{figure}[]
\hspace*{1.5in}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{1.png}}

\begin{equation}             x=l_{s}\cos{q_{s}}+l_{e}\cos({q_{s}+q_{e}})+l_{w}cos({q_{s}+q_{e}+q_{w}})\end{equation}

and 

    \begin{equation}y=l_{s}\sin{q_{s}}+l_{e}\sin({q_{s}+q_{e}})+l_{w}sin({q_{s}+q_{e}+q_{w}}) \end{equation}\\




\newpage
\include{file}
\begin{equation}
x^2+y^2=l_{s}^2+l_{e}^2-2l\cos(\pi-q_{e})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
q_{e}=\arccos(\frac{x^2+y^2-l_{s}^2-l_{e}^2}{2l_{s}l_{e}})
\end{equation}
\newpage
\include{file}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have tried clearpage, cleardouble page or several times typing `\newpage`, 
but it doesn't work. I understand that other similar problems other users had were because of the pictures they inserted, so LaTeX didn't know it was a new page.
I have also tried `\hbox{}\newpage` but to no avail. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: You can't put \newpage in a figure environment. figure is always on one page. Why are you using figure here anyway? And never use `\include` in a figure environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using

```
\begin{figure}[]
\hspace*{1.5in}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{1.png}}
```

and the `figure` environment doesn't end there but only at the end of document i.e., `\end{figure}` comes only before `\end{document}`. The contents inside `figure` environment are put in a box and box can not be broken across pages.

Remedy is to move `\end{figure}` up like

```
\begin{figure}[]
\hspace*{1.5in}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{1.png}}
\end{figure}  %% <--------here
```

and remove it from just before `\end{document}`